# Angular Date pipe showing Invalid date

Tags: angular, angular8, date-pipe

Angular Date pipe not showing Date properly

I am using an angular date pipe on my page list.

```
{{ row.createdDate }} // 2019-11-04T06:32:24.352856
{{ row.createdDate | date: 'mm-dd-yyyy' }} // 32-04-2019
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mm` is minute, you should use `MM`

Answer (score 3):

correct way is like this

```
{{ row.createdDate | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy' }} // 11-04-2019
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
{{ row.createdDate | date: 'shortDate' }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use like this.

```
{{ row.createdDate | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy' }} // This will give you correct date.
```

You can visit [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options) to check the valid format option available for Date Pipe.

Answer (score 1):

For month use `MM`... https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```
{{ date | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go for an exact result.

`"mm"` is minute format, u should capture it as `"MM"` for month.

```
{{ row.createdDate }} // 2019-11-04T06:32:24.352856
{{ row.createdDate | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy' }} // 31-04-2019
```

and the date you captured is **32** is there any reason in that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe
 'mm' for minute
 'MM' for months
 {{ date | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy' }} 

 Examples are given in en-US locale.
 'short': equivalent to 'M/d/yy, h:mm a' (6/15/15, 9:03 AM).
 'medium': equivalent to 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a' (Jun 15, 2015, 9:03:01 AM).
 'long': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a z' (June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM 
 GMT+1).
 'full': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a zzzz' (Monday, June 15, 
 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).
 'shortDate': equivalent to 'M/d/yy' (6/15/15).
 'mediumDate': equivalent to 'MMM d, y' (Jun 15, 2015).
 'longDate': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y' (June 15, 2015).
 'fullDate': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y' (Monday, June 15, 2015).
 'shortTime': equivalent to 'h:mm a' (9:03 AM).
 'mediumTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a' (9:03:01 AM).
 'longTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a z' (9:03:01 AM GMT+1).
 'fullTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a zzzz' (9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00).
```